# UWF commit(like EWF)

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, cmd, windows-8.1

EWF(Enhanced Write Filter) in Windows XP and 7 has a command "commit", for example:

```
ewfmgr c:-commit
```

This command saving all changes to disk at next reboot. Is there a way to do same for UWF(Unified Write Filter) in Windows 8.1? Also, as possible in UWF reset(clear) all changes?

P.S. This should be in the command line or script, not UI.

Comment: UWF does not provide an option to perform commit all rather the application or system must be designed in such a way that you can keep track of changes performed in the system and accordingly invoke CommitFile or CommitRegistry etc. methods. This behavior in UWF is more complicated when compared with EWF but in a way it is more secure because accidental commits of unknown files are prevented with this approach.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69b31980-d0fd-4308-8ddd-c36a78e4a09f/uwf-commit-all?forum=wes8) to the question asked on MSDN forums

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UWF is similar to the File Based Writefilter (FBWF), not to the sector based Enhanced Write Filter (EWF). It is possible to commit single files or registry keys with:

```
uwfmgr File Commit <file>
uwfmgr Registry Commit <key> [<value>]
```

see [UWFMgr Technical Reference (Standard 8)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj979579%28v=winembedded.81%29.aspx)